sh: env-cmd: command not found error when running npm start in my react files
I am developing a webpage using html and react.
When I attempt to run the dev side of my web page (through npm start), I am encountering a
sh: env-cmd: command not found 
error.
I have run npm install and have Node Version 20.12.2.
The script I am running looks as follows,"start": "env-cmd -f development.env react-scripts start",
When I was running the same commands in the main branch, it worked perfectly and I was able to open the webpage in the software of my choosing.
I have also attempted to run
npm install -g env-cmd
however this fails and spits out the errors below. Please let me know if there is anything else I should try - I have already research through stack overflow and netlify and tried the solutions others with the same initial error suggest, but it has not yet solved my issue.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

